# Will I be able to return to football after a wrist fracture?

Tags: football

During a sports activity I fell on an outstretched arm and felt instant pain, but not too severe. The next day I got x-rays which showed a torus fracture of the distal radius. I was put in a cast and still currently am and will be for 4 weeks. The doctor said it would be wise not to return to sports, but it is my last year before high school, and I really want to play. Is there any possibility I'll be able to return to sports?

Comment: The doctor's forecast might be better after these 4 weeks pass and he'll see how you are curing. Don't despair and spend your 4 weeks doing something you really like (choosing from what you doctor allows you).

Comment: It's also possible that the doctor just didn't want you to return to sports while in the cast. You need to ask him specifically next time you see him if/when you can return to sports, and if he says no, then why.

Comment: Doctors can sometimes be overly conservative. A sports medicine doctor may be able to better help you weigh your health vs your athletic goals.

Comment: See a sports doc after the cast comes off. Take it from there. Most of us aren't doctors, we can't diagnose you, and this isn't a medical forum.

Answer (score 3):

You should never ask for medical advise in such an electronic medium, especially when you have already gotten an advise from a professional. Even if there are/were doctors or physiotherapists here, they would not (and should not) give any advise without having examined you in person.

You really should talk to a physio if you are serious about getting back on track with your training, and come up with a proper training plan. Keep in mind that early come-backs are among the most common reasons for serious injuries.

Answer (score 0):

Serious injures have to be taken seriously specially when a professional told you this. I would like to encourage you to do a **serious** rehabilitation and after that re-evaluate the situation.

I understand your feeling as a quit from basketball a couple of years ago for a similar reason. It is frustrating when you really enjoy a specific sport and you have to quit, but your health is a priority.

Comment: Please don't give advice like "I would suggest to continue doing sports...", based on such scarce information. This may do much harm, even if you mean good.

Comment: @Steed Done ...